# How to create query with column computation based on condition from other column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SrNo Name     Amount  ApplyTax
1    John     500      Yes 
2    Peter    700      No
3    Tom      900      Yes
```

If I want to levy tax at 20% on those who have ApplyTax as 1, how do I do that in one query:

The output I need is

```
SrNo Name     Amount  Tax
1    John     500      100
2    Peter    700      0
3    Tom      900      180
```

I am new to SQL so any help would be great.

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select SrNo,Name, Amount , 
case when ApplyTax = 'Yes' then Amount*0.20
else 0
end as Tax
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ApplyTax` column is of type `BIT`, you can do:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      SrNo INT ,
      Amount MONEY ,
      ApplyTax BIT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 500, 1 ),
        ( 2, 700, 0 ),
        ( 3, 900, 1 )


SELECT  SrNo ,
        Amount ,
        Amount * ApplyTax * 0.2 AS TaxAmount
FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
SrNo    Amount  TaxAmount
1       500.00  100.00000
2       700.00  0.00000
3       900.00  180.00000
```

Else you need to apply `CASE` expressions, as in @Rahul Tripathi`s answer.